# series of the Dirac function

Tags: dirac-delta

How to prove that the series
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k\delta^{(k)}(x-k)$$
 converges in $D'$ for all values of $a_k$?
I Understand that the partial sum $$ s_n=\sum_{k=-n}^{n}a_k\delta^{(k)}(x-k)$$ has a compact support $\Rightarrow s_n$ has finite order.

What should I do next?

Comment: By definition you need to show that the sequence  $s_n(\phi)$ is convergent  for every $\phi\in D$. This is clear since $\phi$ has compact support.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  by definition you mean that I should write $\int s_n\cdot\phi dx $?

Comment: No. By definition an element of $D'$ is a bounded linear functional on $D$; in particular $S:D\to\Bbb C$. The value $s(\phi)$ is _not_ in general an integral.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I can't understand the evidence....I've been sitting for two days. Also I can't understand what does $\phi$ mean

Comment: should I say that $s_n->0$ for every n?

Comment: (i) I don't know what you mean when you say you can't understand what $\phi$ means. What's the _definition_ of $D'$??? (ii) No, you shouldn't say $s_n\to0$ for every $n$; that makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The definition  of $D'$ I understand. This is the space of generalized functions, where generalized function is a continuous functional. Also it's written how $(f,\phi)$, where $\phi$ is a continuous function.

Comment: I can't understand what definition I need to use....

Comment: No, a distribution is a continuous linear functional on $D$, the space of infinitely diifferentiable functions with compact support. We write $<f,\phi>$ for $f\in D$, not for continuous $f$!. Next: What's the definition of "$s_n\to s$ in $D'$"? That's the definition you need to use, since that's what you're trying to prove.